# Suspending(), Resuming(), Closed() and Uninitialize() are not being called in IFrameworkView

Tags: winapi, directx-11

I've written a simple DirectX11.2 app, which works. I wanted to add some cleanup code for when the app exits, however I noticed that my window does not actually handle closing, suspending, resuming or uninitializing properly.

According to the IFrameworkView documentation, Uninitialize() should get called before the application exits, but it never gets called (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.core.iframeworkview?view=winrt-19041)

I subscribe to the events that are supposed to fire when a window suspends, resumes, or closes, however it seems like none of those events ever actually fire.

I am under the impression that minimizing the window should **suspend** the application, clicking on the window from the task bar after it has been minimized should **resume** the application, and pressing the red X button in the top right corner of the window should **close** the application, am I wrong?

Here is the relevant code:

```
// the class definition for the core "framework" of our app
ref class App sealed: public IFrameworkView
{
    bool m_windowClosed;
    CGame m_game;

public:
    // this function subscribes to suspend and resume events, and gets called properly
    virtual void Initialize(CoreApplicationView^ appView) {
        // set the OnActivated function to handle to Acivated "event"
        appView->Activated += ref new TypedEventHandler<CoreApplicationView^, IActivatedEventArgs^>(this, &App::OnActivated);
        CoreApplication::Suspending += ref new EventHandler<SuspendingEventArgs^>(this, &App::Suspending);
        CoreApplication::Resuming += ref new EventHandler<Object^>(this, &App::Resuming);

        m_windowClosed = false;
    }

    // this function subscribes to the close() event. This function is called properly, but the Closed event never fires
    virtual void SetWindow(CoreWindow^ window){
        window->Closed += ref new TypedEventHandler<CoreWindow^, CoreWindowEventArgs^>(this, &App::Closed);
    }
    virtual void Load(String^ entryPoint) {}

    virtual void Run() {
        m_game.Initialize();
        
        CoreWindow^ Window = CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread();

        // repeat until window closes
        while (!m_windowClosed) {
            // run processEvents() to dispatch events
            // ProcessAllIfPresent makes ProcessEvents return once all events have been processed
            Window->Dispatcher->ProcessEvents(CoreProcessEventsOption::ProcessAllIfPresent);

            // run the rest of the game code here
            m_game.Update();
            m_game.Render();
        }

        // we never get here!
        m_game.Finalize();
    }

    // never called, even though it should ALWAYS be called when the application exits?
    virtual void Uninitialize() {
        Log("Uninitialize()");
    }

    void OnActivated(CoreApplicationView^ coreAppView, IActivatedEventArgs^ args) {
        CoreWindow^ window = CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread();
        window->Activate();
    }

    // never called
    void Suspending(Object^ sender, SuspendingEventArgs^ args) {
        Log("Suspending()");
    }

    // never called
    void Resuming(Object^ sender, Object^ args) {
        Log("Resuming()");
    }

    // never called
    void Closed(CoreWindow^ sender, CoreWindowEventArgs^ args) { 
        m_windowClosed = true; 
        Log("Close()");
    }
};

// the class definition that creates an instance of our core framework class
ref class AppSource sealed : IFrameworkViewSource {
public:
    virtual IFrameworkView^ CreateView() {
        // create an App class and return it
        return ref new App();
    }
};

[MTAThread]  // define main() as a multi-threaded-apartment function

// the starting point of all programs
int main(Array<String^>^ args) {
    // create and run a new AppSource class
    CoreApplication::Run(ref new AppSource());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In my experience, the application lifecycle events last worked as documented in Windows Phone 8 (and maybe Windows 10 Mobile). On Windows Desktop editions, things never seemed to have followed a predictable scheme for me, maybe due to more complex heuristics or debugger interference. For testing you can [trigger suspend/resume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-trigger-suspend-resume-and-background-events-for-windows-store-apps-in-visual-studio) from Visual Studio's debugger.

Comment: Yes, upon further research, I notice that Suspend and Resume are generally called when Windows itself suspends (sleep, hibernate) and resumes ("wakes up" from sleep or hibernate)

I have now found that the only event that's called before my app terminates is the CoreWindow::VisibilityChanged event. I will use that event for my cleanup code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further research, I notice that Suspend and Resume are generally called when Windows itself suspends (sleep, hibernate) and resumes ("wakes up" from sleep or hibernate).

I have now found that the only event that's called before my app terminates is the CoreWindow::VisibilityChanged event.